# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-security

I decided to modify my application by adding there authentication using `spring security` and database. Before I was using plain authentication with `user` and `password` in XML. It worked fine.

My `authentication-manager` looks like this

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
        users-by-username-query="select username, password from pmc.username_password where username=?;"
        authorities-by-username-query="select a.username, b.role from pmc.username_password a, pmc.username_role b where a.username = b.username and a.username=?;" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

But when I make an attempt to authenticate I've got exception

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select u
sername, password from pmc.username_password where username=?;]; The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.;
 nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.
```

What is wrong in my `sql` syntax in XML file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring Security expects three columns from the user query, in order:

1. username
2. password
3. enabled (boolean)

You don't have the last. If you don't have have an equivalent to "enabled" in your database, you can use a `TRUE` constant.